# Muliple column retrieval from Subquery

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery, in-clause

I have a table tasks  and another table master_employee

i am trying to list some task details  alongside with a String that is going to be parsed  as a json object

```
   SELECT task_name,assignees,priority,
   DATE_FORMAT(due_date, "%M %d %Y") as due_date ,

  (select GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT('{ id:"',emp_id, '",name:"',first_name ,'"}')) as list 
   from master_employee where emp_id in(2925,2913))  as list 
   FROM tasks
   where task_id=4189
```

The String that i was referring to is the is the column alias 'list' .  so the problem is ,as we know subqueries does not return multiple values , the   query returns the concatenated values of only one emp_id .  i want ,for example in this case  concatenated values of emp_id's 2925 and 2913

Comment: Its better if you create your json string in your application layer, from db pull your data and in application code create your json

Comment: @MKhalidJunaid yea  i know that  but  here  i am using the jstl <sql query .  that is why i am asking

Comment: Why are you concatenating stuff ?

Comment: @Strawberry   i am creating a string that is meant to  be parsed as a json object

Comment: But why would you do that, when PHP is perfectly capable of constructing json strings from ordinary arrays !?!

Comment: buddy i m working on jsp @Strawberry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably you are using GROUP_CONCAT function without the GROUP BY clause. if you don't have suitable field for group then just use group by with anything for example 1 or '1'

```
SELECT task_name,assignees,priority,
DATE_FORMAT(due_date, "%M %d %Y") as due_date , (
  select GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT('{ id:"',emp_id, '",name:"',first_name 
  ,'"}')) as list 
  from master_employee where emp_id in(2925,2913)
  GROUP BY '1'
) as list 
FROM tasks
where task_id=4189
```

Comment: thankz  .   this answers my question.  i also want to replace  the emp_id 's inside where clause  with the assignes column  from the main query.. in that case what should i do?

Comment: In subquery you can simply put field name from main query like `emp_id=main_field`
However in your case you may need to use appropriate functions before comparing depending on the data format in the said field from main query. for example if you have something like '2925,2913' then `LOCATE(emp_id,main_field) > 0`

Comment: buddy when i m using  locate(emp_id ,assignees)>0 , it is showing id's that are not in assignees   column

Comment: I think better choice is `FIND_IN_SET(emp_id, assignees) > 0`